# Type or namespace name "SetAuthCookie" does not exist in the namespace "FormAuthentication"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to set cookie for valid user but I am not able to use `SetAuthCookie` as throwing mentioned error. I have added `System.Web.Security` namespace for that but still not able to make use of it. Do I need to install some special nuget package for that?

Here is what I have tried in controller action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(User user)
{
    if (user.Username.ToLower() == "admin" || user.Password == "admin")
    {
        FormAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Username, false);
    }
    return View();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be FormsAuthentication

You missed the 's'